# .htaccess 2 Rewrites, one for delete .php, another with GET

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I get this RewriteRule that works fine:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php
```

But I want another RewriteRule with 1 GET param too:

```
product.php?slug=part-in-0036
```

This works:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ product.php?slug=$1
```

I´m not be able to work both. How those Rewrites would be joined?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ product.php?slug=$1
```